# does quoting order by matter?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using mysql and the following two sqls produce different result.

```
SELECT developers.* FROM "developers" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT developers.* FROM "developers" ORDER BY 'id DESC' LIMIT 1
```

I thought that quoting order by should not matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By quoting the order you are ordering by the literal string 'id DESC', which would indeed change the result, since it's pretty meaningless - little different to saying ORDER BY 1

Answer (score 4):

ORDER BY 'id DESC' is saying "ORDER BY the constant string 'id DESC'".  Don't quote the ORDER BY!  :)